# Image picker is not capturing image from gallery

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to load images from my gallery in the imageview. The application works until the selection of an image. When I select an image from the gallery my application stops responding and I get an error "please restart the application". The block of code which performs this action is mentioned below.

```
@OnClick(R.id.loadImageButton)
    void onLoadImageButtonClick() {

        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
//        final String fname = Utils.getUniqueImageFilename();
//        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
//        uri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, YOUR_SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);

        loadPhotoFromGallery();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == YOUR_SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {

                final boolean isCamera;
                if (data == null) {
                    isCamera = true;
                } else {
                    final String action = data.getAction();
                    if (action == null) {
                        isCamera = false;
                    } else {
                        isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    }
                }

                Uri selectedImageUri;
                if (isCamera) {
                    selectedImageUri = uri;
                } else {
                    selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you check LogCat? There should be an error message.

Comment: Use debug for viewing of exception (using of "logcat"  with "fatal exception" filter) then click on blue links for reaching to error point .Also please give us the error sentence.

Comment: i am checking with exception also but not getting exception also .

Comment: When you exit from the app you see an dialog with "OK" button .please do not press it and then see the logcat

Comment: `root.mkdirs();`. Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exitst() yet. And check the return value. If mkdirs() returns false you should not continue but return.

Comment: `Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)` . That will not pick an image from the gallery but will take a picture. What are you doing?

Comment: `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);`. What is uri? Your code is a mess.

Comment: I am selecting a picture from gallery and after selection Application got stuck and repoen the Application .i want to just replace imageview with my gallery image Uri is defined gloably in my code to provide imagepath

Comment: You are only repeating yourself and not reacting on the camera intent. Please remove all code for camerta intents. Tell the value for uri.toString(). And what about mkdirs() ? Why dont you react?

Comment: can someonehelp me code for image upload from gallery and replace it by imageview .

Comment: We could not see your error message. But please check these items :  1- check the manifest for your permissions for external storage writing and reading  2- run the app  on newer or older android versions. In new versions of android you must have permissions in manifest and also you must implement the permissions requesting in needed points of your program .